# Join (map-matching) observations to roads

Tags: attribute-joins, map-matching

I know that the subject is wide, but I could not find answers to my problem. I have to shapefiles: Roads(c.a. 580 rows and divided into three categories of roads) and observations (detected speed limit signs - c.a 11000 rows). I have to join (map-matching) observations to roads.

I've already tried Spatial Join (match option - closest) in ArcGIS Pro and NNJoin plugin in QGIS, and both gave me some results, but I am still not happy.

The first issue is that the layers have only a geographic coordinate system, and I wonder if they should also have a Projected coordinate system to perform this join?

The second issue is the fact that when using the closest approach some of the points can be assigned to the wrong segment of the road which can give me some errors in the output. I cannot use any other match option because the two layers do not intersect with each other, whatsoever.

How could I approach this issue differently? I've already checked this post:  [Map-matching. Join points to lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393146/map-matching-join-points-to-lines), but this not fully answer my questions.

Comment: Have you tried `join by nearest` using QGIS? Please provide detailed information why you're not happy with the joins you tried. Why do you think CRS has something to do with the output? What rules determine, which road segment a sign belongs to?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works