# How can I get the mean values at intervals of 30 m in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, snapping, segment

I synchronized the GPS point and PM concentration. And I want to get the mean value every 30m. What should I do?
[image: I snapped the points to path]
I snapped the points to path
[image: And I want to a results like this picture.]
And I want to the results like this picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387207/88814